# How to load balance a website in different droplets in digitalocean

Tags: php, nginx, redis, load-balancing, mariadb

I am really new to load balancing as most of the time, I only do web development on just one machine or vps.

How can I load balance a website that runs on ubuntu, nginx, php, redis and mariadb to two or more droplets in Digitalocean?

I am more concern on the redis and mariadb side. My only Idea right now is to have one droplet (droplet A) only for redis and mariadb and two droplets (droplet B,C) for load balancing the requests that contains the php applications but still it will connect to droplet A for the data. Is this right? If not, how can I do this specifically for redis and mariadb (I dont know how to setup them for two or more machines).

Specific steps would be awesome as I am a newbie at this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have not mentioned "replication" or "clustering", so we don't know what the relationship is between the two servers running MariaDB.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rick, can you site whats better between the two if you are just starting up with two droplets. what are the advantages and disadvantages? and what do you propose between the two base on your experience and scaling better. forgive me, i know its too broad but I am all clueless at this at this.Your input will give me a good start. thanks

Comment: How many queries per second will you be having?  How many GB of data?

Comment: lets start around 500 to a thousand request per second with probably around 1 to 2mb per request, this is just an estimate . I am also forecasting the possibility for it to increase even more. I just want to start on the right foot and use an efficient stable setup for this scenario and for scaling up. thanks

Comment: If those are `INSERTs`, that sounds like _3 terabytes per hour_?  Please elaborate on how you plan to provision even a month's worth of disk space.  Also, explain what kind of disk system can sustain 1GB/sec.

Comment: Not inserts, for inserts, it would just be inserting the minimal as possible basic data around bytes as I am putting asset files and user uploads on an amazon s3 server. What i mean by 1 to 2mb is the whole actual web page size where asset files are included. Probably for the database it would be just in bytes for all transactions.

Comment: The web page is not in question here.  Please edit your question to add some numbers.  If the numbers are small enough, I will simply say you don't need redis, nor two machines.  If the numbers are big enough (but not huge), we need to discuss replication or clustering, so the two servers can stay in sync.

Comment: @Rick, thanks, lets say we have really high numbers. How can I set this up with clustering or replication? for the two machines. I really want to learn and apply this with redis and mariadb for two or more machines for my personal projects. can you provide me some basic initial steps for newbies? thanks

Comment: Start by reading the section in the MySQL manual on Replication (it applies to MariaDB, too).  Then move on to Galera Clustering (it comes with MariaDB).  There is far too much to say in this forum.